# Called application is closing terminal session when it exits

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a GO application, which at some point executes `os.Exit(1)` because of an error that happens, the problem is that it is closing my terminal as well, not only terminating the app.

I am calling the application like this
`application --param1 1`

How can I prevent that the application will not close my terminal and how can I get the exit status from it?

Comment: Have you set the `errexit` shell option in your shell before running the application? You should be able to check whether this option is set with `set -o | grep errexit`. If it's set, the shell would exit if the application returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: You could also (probably) configure your terminal to not close when the command exits. With many terminal programs, this can be set in a different profile than your day-to-day usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have set `errexit` that makes shell exit whenever the command returns not zero exit status. You can disable this behavior with `set +e` command. Other thing that you can do is making  bash `or` with `true` command. The invocation will look like:

```bsh
application --param1 1 || true
```

Comment: Nail it. Actually, I was calling `set -e`. Thanks